# Git on Windows: could not create leading directories error

Tags: windows, git

I have installed **MsysGit** on Windows. The following command invoked from the cmd.exe command-line gives error:

```
C:\Users\joe>git clone 'git://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager-known-repositories.git' 'C:/Users/joe/vim-addons/vim-addon-manager-known-repositories'
fatal: could not create leading directories of ''C:/Users/joe/vim-addons/vim-addon-manager-known-repositories'': Invalid argument
```

The same command issued in the command prompt of **Git Bash** works fine.

What do I fix to make the normal command-line version work? This command is issued from within Vim, so I need it to work from cmd.exe.

Comment: If you launch vim from a msysgit bash session instead of a classic DOS session, would it work then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't use single quotes on windows cmd. Use double quotes for paths with spaces, or no quotes at all when no spaces exist.

In your case, no spaces are in the path, so no quotes are necessary.

E.g.

```
C:\path\no\spaces               // ok
"C:\Program Files\Some Spaces"  // ok
'C:\Program Files\Foo'          // wrong.
```

Comment: I am not issuing this command. It is issued from within the vim-addon-manager script of Vim.

Comment: Alex: Turns out I had shellslash turned on in Vim. Removed the :set shellslash line and the paths are properly quoted now. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this issue in github of vunble.

https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/issues/283

The solution is very simple, just comment the line of shellslash with  '"'

Best wishes.